# How to find out programmatically if port, input-ed by user is being used by a particular service?

Tags: visual-c++

I want to install a Major upgrade of an application, the application uses particular services which listens at ports given as input by the user. The check for Port In Use is done programmatically before previous version of application is uninstalled and it's upgrade is installed.

I want my installer to allow its services listen at particular ports if the previous version of the application's services are listening at the same ports as input-ed by the user while doing major upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious about this approach, determine the PID of your running service and then look for it in the result of [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL` set.

However, I suppose you will have a much easier time forgetting about the actual listen sockets and just looking for the configuration information in the registry or config files, so maybe you should rethink your approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response Themel.Registry and the config files do not contain information on ports numbers being used by my application's services.:(

Comment: Then how does the installed application know which port number to listen on?